# Using a shape file to download MODIS product data for country in R

Tags: r, r-modis

Is there any way that can be used to parse a shapefile of a country and download MODIS product data within that country using R?

I tried different approaches using the `MODIStsp` package (https://docs.ropensci.org/MODIStsp/) as well as the `MODISTools` package (https://docs.ropensci.org/MODISTools/articles/modistools-vignette.html) and they both only allow me to download MODIS product data for a defined site, but not a country.

Comment: Do you have an example of the data you're trying to download?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you might achieve this.

Firstly, download the MODIS data that you require, in this example I'm using MCD12Q1.006

`begin_year` and `end_year` are in the format: Year.Month.Days.
`shape_file` is the shapefile you're using, presumably the extent of the shapefile is the country you're after. Though, I'm only going off by the minimal information you have provided.

```
library(MODIS)

tifs <- runGdal(product = "MCD12Q1", collection = "006", SDSstring = "01", 
                extent = shape_file %>% st_buffer(dist = 10000), 
                begin = begin_year, end = end_year, 
                outDirPath = "data", job = "modis",
                MODISserverOrder = "LPDAAC") %>% 
  pluck("MCD12Q1.006") %>% 
  unlist()
```

```
# rename tifs to have more descriptive names
new_names <- format(as.Date(names(tifs)), "%Y") %>% 
  sprintf("modis_mcd12q1_umd_%s.tif", .) %>% 
  file.path(dirname(tifs), .)
file.rename(tifs, new_names)

landcover <- list.files("data/modis", "^modis_mcd12q1_umd", 
                        full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  stack()
# label layers with year
landcover <- names(landcover) %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=modis_mcd12q1_umd_)[0-9]{4}") %>% 
  paste0("y", .) %>% 
  setNames(landcover, .)
```

Also, if you require a particular cell size, then you could follow this procedure to get a 5x5 modis cell size.

```
neighborhood_radius <- 5 * ceiling(max(res(landcover))) / 2

agg_factor <- round(2 * neighborhood_radius / res(landcover))
r <- raster(landcover) %>% 
  aggregate(agg_factor) 
r <- shape_file %>% 
  st_transform(crs = projection(r)) %>% 
  rasterize(r, field = 1) %>% 
  # remove any empty cells at edges
  trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using MODISTools to automate downloading the correct tiles for the country.

First let's generate a polygon of a country to demonstrate (using Luxembourg as an example):

```
library(maptools)
library(sf)
data(wrld_simpl)
world = st_as_sf(wrld_simpl)
lux = world[world$NAME=='Luxembourg',]
```

Now we find the location (centroid) and size of the country:

```
#find centroid of polygon in long-lat decimal degrees
lux.cent = st_centroid(lux)

#find width and height of country in km
lux.proj = st_transform(lux, 
           "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs")
lux.km_lr = diff(st_bbox(lux.proj)[c(1,3)])
lux.km_ab = diff(st_bbox(lux.proj)[c(2,4)])
```

Using this info, we can download the correct Modis data (using leaf-area index, lai, as an example):

```
#download the MODIS tiles for the area we defined
library(MODISTools)
lux_lai <- mt_subset(product = "MOD15A2H",
                          lat = lux.cent$LAT, lon =  lux.cent$LON,
                          band = "Lai_500m",
                          start = "2004-01-01", end = "2004-01-01",
                          km_lr = lux.km_lr, km_ab = lux.km_ab,
                          site_name = "Luxembourg",
                          internal = TRUE, progress = TRUE)

# convert to a spatial raster
lux.rast = mt_to_raster(df = lux_lai, reproject = TRUE)
lux.rast = raster::mask(lux.rast, lux)
plot(lux.rast)
plot(st_geometry(lux),add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Can the same be done in Python?